# Size report builder image from database columns

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0

I have a report in Report Builder 2012 3.0 that I'm trying to make. It shows an image in a tablix. The image is saved in the database table as binary data. I also have 2 columns with the 'actual width' and the 'actual height'.

Is there a way that I can use so that I can transfer the 'actual width' and 'actual height' with the image in my report and that it will show the image in this width and height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSRS doesn't support specifying object sizes through expressions. The only control you have is with the image `Sizing` and `Padding` properties. These are fairly limited and would not be practical for dynamically sizing images. Even other workarounds like using the image as the background for a different object are not feasible. So unfortunately SSRS is not the best tool for this requirement.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for. Thanks anyway!